# Which approach to storing loading processes is preferable?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk, setstate

Can You please help to decide which one of the architectures will be better
(fetching list from API with with react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk)

1. example

```js
// component
componentDidMount() {
 this.props.dispatch(fetchFunction());
}

// thunk action
fetchFunction () {

 dispatch START_LOADING

 return dispatch (
  fetch()
   dispatch SUCCESS_LOADING
 );

}
```

OR

2. example

```js
// component
componentDidMount() {
 this.setState({'loading': true})
 this.props.dispatch(fetchFunction()).finally(
  this.setState({'loading': false})
 );
}

//thunk action
fetchFunction () {

 return dispatch (
  fetch()
   dispatch SUCCESS_LOADING
 );

}
```

My idea is about storing "loading process" in local components state? What are bad and good sides of this approaches?

as i see it - example 2:

If loading takes longer time, i can leave component (it gets unmounted) and i will see warning - "changing state on unmounted component"

1 example:
Saves a lot of extra data that i do not need in redux store (also a lot of data i need to exclude from persist), and for example if i have a web store product component, i will have a lot of UI props stored in redux (for example list with 10 products, and each product has it's own buttons with states) :(
BUT i like it because all the logic stays in redux-thunk-actions, and i do not need to care in component how to continue coding after dispatch, whether it was a promise or wasn't example:

```js
 this.props.dispatch(fetchFunction()).then(() => {});
```

or just

```js
 this.props.dispatch(fetchFunction());
 .. some code
```

So far I've made simple projects, and both ways worked fine.
Can you please give some advice which way to go for the bigger project?

Comment: @Perniferous, your comment isn't useful without some explanation, and if you have some it should be included in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If components outside of this component's tree need to know about the loading state, then keep the loading state in the store so that those outside components can query that state.

In a large app, whether a components need to know of a given piece of state is something can changes; starting out, Component X has local state because no other components need to know about local state X, but as the app grows, new components, thunks, etc are introduced that do need to know about local state X, and it has to be moved to the store. So to address this, one approach is to put all state in Redux from the beginning so you don't have to worry about unforeseen refactoring of local to global state.

Keeping everything in the redux store also makes debugging easier because you can see all the values in redux devtools rather than having to find individual components to see their local state.

Comment: the idea is of course that they do not need to know that information, but i am aware of the ugly code in component, the first example gives me the opportunity just to dispatch some actions and not to worry about what is returned, the changed props will handle the changes in the ui..

Comment: of course if i am having some radio button, i will save selected option inside state,
but loading state is connected to dispatched action, isn't there such philosophy - "what goes to dispatch - stays in dispatch"? :D